# After capturing image on mobile device the preview is not that exact

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, canvas

The problem can be seen in attached image. The capture area and captured image are not that much exact...
[image]

Here is the code which is taking snapshot.

```
var takeSnapshot = function () {
    const deviceWidth = $(window).width();
    let widthForSmallDevice = 270;
    let heightForSmallDevice = 202.5;
    if (deviceWidth <= 419 && deviceWidth >= 340) {
        widthForSmallDevice = 310;
        heightForSmallDevice = 220;
    } else if (deviceWidth <= 499 && deviceWidth >= 420) {
        widthForSmallDevice = 380;
        heightForSmallDevice = 290;
    } else if (deviceWidth >= 500) {
        widthForSmallDevice = 400;
        heightForSmallDevice = 300;
    }
    if ($('#dest').is(':hidden')) {
        canvas.width = videoElement[0].videoWidth;
        canvas.height = videoElement[0].videoHeight;
        destCanvas.width = widthForSmallDevice;
        destCanvas.height = heightForSmallDevice;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(videoElement[0], 0, 0, widthForSmallDevice, heightForSmallDevice);
        destCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        destCtx.canvas.style.display = 'inline-block';
        $('#frontImageCapturedLable').show();
        $('#backImageClick').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#captureArea').hide();
        $('#backVideo').trigger('play');
        $('#backImageCameraSelect').show();
        $('#confirmationDiv').show();
    } else {
        canvas1.width = backImageVideoElement[0].videoWidth;
        canvas1.height = backImageVideoElement[0].videoHeight;
        backCanvas.width = widthForSmallDevice;
        backCanvas.height = heightForSmallDevice;
        canvas1.getContext('2d').drawImage(backImageVideoElement[0], 0, 0, widthForSmallDevice, heightForSmallDevice);
        backImage.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
        backImage.canvas.style.display = 'inline-block';
        $('#backImageCapturedLable').show();
        $('#backImageCaptureArea').hide();
    }
    if ($('#dest').is(':visible') && $('#backImage').is(':visible')) {
        $('#frontImageResetButton').show();
        $('#backImageResetButton').show();
    }
};
```

Can anyone suggest tell mw what is wrong in the above code and how can I get rid of the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more precise about "are not that much exact"? I see two different images taken from two different points of view (different perspective).. it's difficult to know what is exact or not if we don't know what you expect them to be

Comment: Sure. The first image is input. I am opening a video source and capturing the image when clicking on take snapshot button we get the second image which is output of the first video source. is it enough or do I need to more precise

Comment: So the first being a live video and the second a snapshot of it, are you sure you didn't move your device after having captured the snap? If there is something like a cropping issue, it's hard to tell with your example as the point of view obviously changed (different perspective). So I'm still unsure what the problem actually is

Comment: Yes I am sure that after taking snapshot I dint move camera.

Comment: Ok, the apparent change in perspective could be simply due to a change of vertical scale. Do you have any way to control which one is the correct one, the live preview or the snapshot? (you can try to open the camera app and compare to see which one is good)